# App Shortcut only works once, just resumes the app after that

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-appshortcut

I have a dynamic app shortcut which looks like this

```
ShortcutInfo composeShortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(App.getInstance(),
                                                                           getString(R.string.compose_shortcut_id))
                    .setShortLabel(getString(R.string.compose_app_shortcut_short_label))
                    .setLongLabel(getString(R.string.compose_app_shortcut_long_label))
                    .setDisabledMessage(getString(R.string.compose_app_shortcut_disabled_message))
                    .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(App.getInstance(), R.drawable.compose_icon))
                    .setIntent(new Intent(context, ComposeActivity.class))
                                              .setAction(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT)
                                              .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP))
                    .build();
            shortcutManager.setDynamicShortcuts(Arrays.asList(composeShortcut));
```

First time when I click this shortcut, it opens `ComposeActivity` just fine but not after that, I have to kill the app after which it works again for one time.

**Desired flow** - Whenever I click the app shortcut, the ComposeActivity should open. If the app is already running then ComposeActivity should open on top of the current activity only if the current activity is not already a ComposeActivity.

**Current flow** - First time I press the app shortcut, Compose activity opens just fine, but not after that. App is only resumed after that. I have to kill the app and again click the shortcut for it to open the ComposeActivity.

More info - 
Compose Activity in AndroidManifest is defined like this:

```
...
<activity 
android:name=".shared.publish.compose.view.activity.ComposeActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@style/compose_theme"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"/>

<activity
    android:name=".shared.activity.SplashScreenActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/splash_screen_theme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
...
```

Comment: Please explain what you want to happen. And post your manifest.

Comment: @DavidWasser I have updated the que with AndroidManifest code and whats desired.

Comment: Please post your entire manifest. Or a least the <activity> tag with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER

Comment: @DavidWasser Whole manifest would be way too big. Added activity with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER.

Comment: What happens after `ComposeActivity` is launched. What happens next? Does `ComposeActivity` launch other activities?

Comment: The problem is complicated and depends on how the rest of your application flow (navigation between activities) works.

Comment: @DavidWasser User can launch new activities from ComposeActivity. On backpress also I check `isTaskRoot()`, if true then I navigate him to the HomeScreen.

Comment: Post the code for `ComposeActivity.getCallingIntent()` please

Comment: @DavidWasser updated the code, have replaced `ComposeActivity.getCallingIntent()`.

Comment: `ShortcutInfo` is available only starting with API 25. Are you using the compatibility class? Also, what device are you testing on. Does that device has API 25 or higher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the solution. Thanks to some useful information from David Wasser.

Firstly App shortcut works for Activity with Action `MAIN` and Category `LAUNCHER`.

So in manifest I added the following intent filter to my ComposeActivity

```
 <Activity android:name=".view.activity.ComposeActivity"
     android:relinquishTaskIdentity="true">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
     </intent-filter> 
 </Activity>
```

If you look closely I have also set `android:relinquishTaskIdentity="true"`. This makes sure that if I have already open the ComposeActivity from shortcut and then I can again use it and open ComposeActivity.

Next I updated the Intent used for Shortcut

```
new Intent(context, ComposeActivity.class))
.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
```

By doing this, ComposeActivity will always open if it already not on top of the activity stack. Also it will open on top of any existing activity.

But there is one problem. If there is no activity open, then Compose will not have any activity below it. App will close if back button is pressed.

One thing you can do is

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(isTaskRoot()){
        if (getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) 
              && Intent.ACTION_MAIN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            //launch any activity
        }
    }
    finish();
}
```

With this I could have any activity to open when ComposeActivity is the only activity in the back stack. In my case I launched my HomeActivity.

Answer (score 1):

As I expected, the problem is due to your use of the `ShortcutManager`. Here is the important bit from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html):

> Only main activities—activities that handle the MAIN action and the
>   LAUNCHER category—can have shortcuts. If an app has multiple main
>   activities, these activities have different sets of shortcuts.

What happens is that your shortcut `Intent` looks like a launcher `Intent`. When the user clicks on an app icon, this generates a launcher `Intent` (ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER). Android then looks to see if there is already an active task that has this launcher `Activity` as the root `Activity`. If it finds one, all it does is bring that task to the foreground. If it doesn't find one, it creates a new task and launches the launcher `Activity` into the new task as the root `Activity`. This is exactly the behaviour that you are seeing, and is exactly what users expect. If you are using Gmail or some other app and then you take a call (pushing that app to the background), then when you return to the HOME screen and click that app icon again, you expect to to brought back to the app exactly the way you left it. This is standard and expected Android behaviour.

Please also read the section in the documentation titled "Shortcut Intents", which includes this gem:

> Dynamic shortcuts can be published with any set of Intent flags.
>   Typically, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK is specified, possibly along with
>   other flags; otherwise, if the app is already running, the app is
>   simply brought to the foreground, and the target activity may not
>   appear.

You need to rethink your navigation so that it makes sense for the users (and it follows the standard Android patterns).

Comment: Thats some great information. Thanks. But I know the kind of navigation I am looking for is possible. Telegram has exactly the same use case for their `New Conversation` shortcut. It works just fine.

Comment: Well, I don't know the app. You might want to look at that app's Manifest to see how they are doing this. Or you can use `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` to see what the activity stack looks like while using their app. I'm sure that there is probably a way to get what you want, but you might need to use 2 different tasks, or use a different technique for launching your app in general, etc.